# Displaying Integers on QLabels?

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

Basically i'm making a simple calculator program to understand the basics of C++ GUI however I get an error message leading to the line of code I have in the `void MainWindow::addx()` to `label -> setText(c);` with an error message of:

```
invalid user-defined conversion from 'int' to 'const QString&'[-fpermissive]
```

I really don't know what that error message means I assume it means I cant display an integer on a label. I just wanted to know if I am able to display an integer on my label or do I have to use a different widget.

```
class MainWindow() {
   int a, b, c;
   QLabel * label;
   ...
};

void MainWindow::addx()
    c = a + b;
    label -> setText(c);
}
```

Comment: I have a serious suggestion: just because you *can* copy and paste a lot of code easily when using a computer, it doesn't mean that it's how you should be asking questions here. Please appreciate the time and willingness to help of everyone here by not abusing us with walls of text. Showing your code doesn't mean mindlessly copy-pasting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to convert it:

```
firstnumberx();
secondnumberx();
c = a+b;
label->setText(QString::number(c));
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! But for some reason its not outputting c but a large random number.

Comment: @user3183586 maybe you don't read values of spinners to a and b before adding (thus a and b are random memory contents)?

Comment: I think I did read the values in with  b = spinner->value(); im not sure.

Comment: @user3183586 you wrote the methods but you don't run them, add `firstnumberx(); secondnumberx();` before `c = a+b` in `addx()`

Answer (score 5):

This should work..

```
label -> setText(QString::number(c));
```

If you need to add multiple number inside some string you can try below..

```
label -> setText(QString("%1").arg(c));
```

Comment: Thanks it compiles now! However when I try to add two numbers it gives a random 7 digit number.

Comment: @user3183586 large number..? is it out of range or int?

Comment: That gives me an error as well "cannot call member function 'QString QString::arg(int, int, int, QChar) const' without object. Also it gives a large integer.

Comment: @user3183586 did you use arg as above (edited answer)?

Answer (score 2):

`QLabel` has `setNum()` methods taking `int` or `double` arguments:

```
label->setNum(c);
```

The `setNum()` methods format the supplied number and then set the `text` property with the formatted value.  The documentation does not specify which locale is used for formatting, so you may wish to experiment.